# NullInjectorError: No provider for NotifierQueueService! Karma Angualr 6

Tags: unit-testing, notifications, angular6, karma-jasmine

Am using angular-notifier in my application .It is working well with imports 
import { NotifierModule } from 'angular-notifier';
in app.module.ts

and in spec.ts of component i have added import { NotifierService } from 'angular-notifier';

providers: [NotifierService] in TestBed

NullInjectorError: No provider for NotifierService : This resolved with above import in spec.ts

After that am facing this issue : NullInjectorError: No provider for NotifierQueueService!

I didn't find any import on NotifierQueueService.

Please help me with this am struggling with 2 working days .Do we have any solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

You should include NotifierModule into 'imports' section

```js
import { NotifierService, NotifierModule } from 'angular-notifier';

// ...
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [NotifierModule]
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually a lack of service injection in providers.

Try add NotifierQueueService in providers inside TestBed.configureTestingModule

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [],
    providers: [NotifierQueueService] // Here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

in service class after import section check whether below code is there

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```